# No se muestran los componentes en ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Buenas, estaba probando los export por default en [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs), pero al momento de usar el servidor que trae [npm](/questions/tagged/npm), no me visualiza los componentes, ni nada por el estilo.

Este es el código que uso en el `index.js`.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

import tablaProductos from "./componentes/tablaProductos.js";

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(<tablaProductos/>, app);
```

Y aquí esta el código que uso en la clase `tablaProductos`:

```
var React = require('react');

import busqueda from "./busqueda.js";
import products from "./products.js";

export default class tabaProductos extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <busqueda/>
                <products/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

El problema es que no lo muestra en la página.

Comment: Primero, npm no tiene ningún servidor, no sé a qué te refieres. Segundo, React no usa la sintaxis de JavaScript, si no, JSX, que es una extensión de JavaScript especial para la inclusión de HTML en JavaScript. Tercero, necesitas un transpilador que convierta código JSX a JavaScript, ya que el navegador no entiende JSX. Por consiguiente, ¿Dónde está tu configuración de Webpack, Gulp, FuseBox o Grunt para transpilar JSX?

Comment: que error te muestra en los devtools? tal vez es un "typo", tu clase se llama `tabaProductos` y en tu index.js estas importando `tablaProductos`.

Answer (score 3):

El problema queda en que los componentes de React tienen que ser capitalizados. Los componentes que no lo son serán interpretados por Babel como elementos nativos del DOM. O sea:

```
<tablaProductos/>
```

Será transpilado así:

```
React.createElement("tablaProductos", null)
```

y no así:

```
React.createElement(tablaProductos, null)
```

cual es una referencia a la clase `tablaProductos` y es lo que quieres. Para arreglarlo, cambia el nombre de la clase `tablaProductos` a `TablaProductos` (cosa que debes hacer ni modo, ya que es lo normal capitalizar los nombres de las clases). Entonces, haz:

```
import TablaProductos from "./componentes/TablaProductos.js";

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(<TablaProductos/>, app);
```

Y Babel lo transpilará correctamente.

Igual con las clases `busqueda` y `products`. Cámbialos a `Busqueda` y `Products`.